# python flask: how to align the form in the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to put the login form in the login.html which created by 'bootstrap/wtf.html. But the form of username password et al aligned left as the following image. I want to put the form in the center.

[image: login image]

The code is following:

```
    {% extends "common/base.html" %}

{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
{#{% import "macros/_patination.html" as page_macros %}#}

{#<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css">#}

{% block content %}
<div class = "main-login">

    <h1>{{ _('Sign In') }}</h1>
    <div class="main-form">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>{{ _('New User?') }} <a href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">{{ _('Click to Register!') }}</a></p>
    <p>
        {{ _('Forgot Your Password?') }}
        <a href="{{ url_for('auth.reset_password_request') }}">{{ _('Click to Reset It') }}</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

and css style code:

```
.main-login{
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-form{
  /*padding-top: 100px;*/
  text-align: center;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}
```

Comment: In fact this is not about python or flask, could you reduce your example to the HTML & CSS you get in browser ? it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the section of code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
```

And you should be good.